# How to check whether $f(X)=X^4-6X^2+1$ is irreducible or not in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

How to check whether $f(X)=X^4-6X^2+1$ is irreducible or not in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

I have tried to apply Eisenstein's Criterion to a linear substitution, to reduce the $f(X)$ modulo a prime and to write it as $(X^2+aX+c)(X^2+bX+d)$, but all without success.

I know that $f(X)$ has four zeros, namely  $\pm\sqrt{\frac{6\pm 4\sqrt{2}}{2}}$, these are all not in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't think we can conclude anything from this.

Any hints on how to approach this problem? Or on what method to use when I get stuck like this?

An idea that just crossed my mind was to reduce modulo a prime and then try to write it as something of the form $(X^2+aX+c)(X^2+bX+d)$, which I can see doesn't work for $p=2$, as (X^4+X^2+1)=(X^2+x+1)^2 in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$, I haven't tried to work any others out yet.

Comment: HINT: $$X^4-6X^2+1= (X^4 - 2X^2+1) - 4X^2$$

Comment: The roots are *not* $\pm\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{2}$, as you wrote, as in that case the polynomial would be $(x^2+3)(x^2-2)$, but that product is $x^4  + x^2 - 6$.

Comment: @KCd Correct, they are $\pm\sqrt{\frac{6\pm 4\sqrt{2}}{2}}$, will edit them.

Comment: @Crostul I got it with KCd's answer, but how would this hint work?

Comment: @JackpotWizard180 You can explicitly factor the polynomial using this decomposition. Recognise both terms as squares and apply difference of two squares

Comment: @FShrike Ah so we have $(X^2-1)^2-(2X)^2$, and this equals $((X^2-1)+2X)((X^2-1)-2X)$ by the difference of two squares. So we have $f(X)=(X^2+2X-1)(X^2-2X-1)$, and conclude that our polynomial is reducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monic irreducible factors in $\mathbf Q[x]$ of a monic polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$ are in $\mathbf Z[x]$ (Gauss's lemma). There are no roots in $\mathbf Z$, so if the polynomial were reducible in $\mathbf Q[x]$ then it would equal
$$
(x^2 + ax + c)(x^2 + bx + d)
$$
in $\mathbf Z[x]$, so $cd = 1$. Thus $c = d = 1$ or $c = d = -1$.  Try each of those cases to solve for $a$ and $b$ as integers. If it works out in one case then you have shown the polynomial is reducible. If it doesn't work in either case then you have shown the polynomial is irreducible.